# How to unban a user from a particular server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

A user with the Minecraft name `someuser` can't connect to my server and gets the following error:

[image: Error message]

In the log file I see this:

```
31.01 12:21:10 [Disconnect] User com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile@113f3c3e[id=[...],
name=someuser,properties={textures=[com.mojang.authlib.properties.Property@b4ee432]},
legacy=false] (/[...]) has disconnected, reason: 
You are banned from this server!
```

He isn't a griefer. Whitelist is enabled, and `someuser` is on it. The server is *Vanilla Minecraft Server (1.8.8)*. He is not banned in the *Users* panel of Multicraft.

How can I fix it (i. e. allow the user to connect to my server again) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/pardon-ip <ip-address>` fixed the problem.

Comment: But only if the user got an IP ban.

Answer (score 6):

You have to type `/pardon someuser` to unban a player.

Comment: Be sure that no plugin is currently blocking the access. For default, you can go with the command mentioned above.

Comment: With some servers you can also just do `/ban username` and if their banned it will unban them